# Wrapping C create and destroy functions using a smart pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, smart-pointers, cross-language

I have some C API that handles object creation and destruction, it provides: `createObject(...)` and `destroy(...)`. I want to wrap it into some more modern construction/destruction mechanisms and use them with smart pointers. I am afraid that at some point I will forget to destroy the object, or some exception will occur.

I am aware of custom deleter function for `shared_ptr`, but I can't explicitly call `new`, because `createOjbect` function handles initialization.

Can I use STL smart pointers in this situation? Do I have to, from scratch, implement a class with initialization in constructor, destruction in destructor and reference counting in this situation?

Comment: Why do you need ref counter in your class? Just call createObject in constructor, destroy in destructor and provide some static factory function that will return smart pointer to your class. Smart pointer will handle refcounter part. When your class is finally destructed - it will automatically call destroy

Comment: What does createObject return?  What does it take?  Depending on your answer there can be improvments.

Comment: Why would you even do that, you have to use `.get()` everywhere where you want to call C API in your wrapper.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is fully capable to create and delete an object with cutstom creator and deleter, but instead of [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) you have to use the creator function.

Let's consider, we have the following creator and deleter:

```
typedef struct {
    int m_int;
    double m_double;
} Foo;

Foo* createObject(int i_val, double d_val) {
    Foo* output = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));

    output->m_int = i_val;
    output->m_double = d_val;

    puts("Foo created.");
    return output;
}

void destroy(Foo* obj) {
    free(obj);
    puts("Foo destroyed.");        
}
```

To manage an instance of `Foo` created by functions above, simply do the following:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo(createObject(32, 3.14), destroy);
```

---

Using the [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is an overhead if you don't wish to share the object's ownership. In this case the [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is much better but for this type you have to define a custom deleter functor with which it can delete the managed `Foo` instance:

```
struct FooDeleter {
    void operator()(Foo* p) const {
        destroy(p);
    }
};
using FooWrapper = std::unique_ptr<Foo, FooDeleter>;

/* ... */

FooWrapper foo(createObject(32, 3.14));
```

Comment: I'd add that you can often just pass C's free as the deleter function.

Comment: Why would you even do that, you have to use .get() everywhere where you want to call C API in your wrapper. How hard is it to just call destroy in destructor? It's less obvious than explicit C API call.

Comment: @Konrad you can't "just" call destroy, because you also need to think about what happens if the class is copied or moved, and define or delete other special members. Using a small pointer class stoves that for you. Having to call `get()` is a small price to pay, you seem more concerned about a few characters than code which is correct and safe.

Comment: @JonathanWakely it doesn't apply if I never copy/move it

Answer (score 6):

C++17.

```
template<auto X> using constant_t=std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(X)>, X>
template<auto X> constexpr constant_t<X> constant{};
template<class T, auto dtor> using smart_unique_ptr=std::unique_ptr< T, constant_t<dtor> >;
```

Now suppose you have a C API wrapping `Bob`  with `Bob* createBob(some_args...)` and `destroyBob(Bob*)`:

```
using unique_bob=smart_unique_ptr< Bob, destroyBob >;
unique_bob make_unique_bob(some_args args){
  return unique_bob( createBob(args) );
}
```

a `unique_bob` can be implicitly moved into a `shared_ptr<Bob>`.

A bit of an extra assumption can make this work in C++14:

```
template<class T, void(*dtor)(T*)> using smart_unique_ptr=std::unique_ptr< T, std::integral_constant<decltype(dtor),dtor> >;
```

which assumes the dtor signature is `void(T*)`.

In C++11 you have to write a new stateless function pointer dispatcher for zero overhead unqiue ptrs.

Comment: I like your solution with `std::integral_constant`.

Comment: Why would you even do that, you have to use `.get()` everywhere where you want to call C API in your wrapper. How hard is it to just call `destroy` in destructor? It's less obvious than explicit C API call.

Comment: @Konrad Failing to call `get()` the compiler tells you; your code doesn't compile.  Yay, incorrect code didn't compile.  Falling to call `destroy` your code silently leaks.  Boo, incorrect code compiles.  Things that are checked at compile time *don't happen* at runtime.  This isn't about making code require fewer characters, it is about making code where entire categories of errors don't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Posting full solution for my case:

Based on @Akira's suggestions I wrapped it using shared pointer, because I want this object shared in many palaces, and lambda:

```
// coming from some API:
struct SomeStruct;
bool initializedata(SomeStruct **data);
bool destorycdata(SomeStruct **data);

class SomeStructWrapper
{
public:
    SomeStructWrapper()
    {
        SomeStruct* data;
        if(initializedata(&data))
        {
            m_data = std::shared_ptr<SomeStruct>(data, [](SomeStruct* ptr){
                destorycdata(&ptr);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Data was not initalized");
        }
    }

    const SomeStruct* operator->() const {return m_data.get();}
    SomeStruct* operator->() {return m_data.get();}

private:
    std::shared_ptr<SomeStruct> m_data;
};
```